# Sierpinski Triangle Java

Tags: java, png

I am having trouble writing a program that prints out a sierpinkski triangle. I am having trouble getting started with the actual code, I wrote some basic methods below. Thanks

```
public class Assignment11 {

  private static Graphics2D g2d;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(800, 693, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    sierpinski(400, 0, 0, 692, 799, 692);
    g2d.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("as11.png"));
  }

  private static void sierpinski(double topX, double topY, double leftX,
      double leftY, double rightX, double rightY) {

  }
}
```

Comment: You have not written some basic methods.  You wrote the basic method that starts off every Java program, and want us to fill in the hard part.  What have you tried to make the triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sierpinski triangle graphically is an object that has smaller objects in it and so on. Each triangle has three coordinates top, bottom-left, bottom-right from that you can draw a triangle. 
You start with a triangle (**triangle1**) of maximum size. Next you find for each edge of this triangle it's mid-point. Once you have mid-points
    midpoint1:   from (topx ; topy ) to (leftx ; lefty )
    midpoint2:   from (topx ; topy ) to (rightx; righty)
    midpoint3:   from (leftx; lefty) to (rightx; righty)
you draw another triangle through the points (midpoint1, midpoint2, midpoint3). This triangle graphically divides **triangle1** into three smaller triangles of equal size. Now you repeat the process for each of these three triangles. And so on until you are in the situation when the triangle can not be divided further (say you end with triangle of edges 1 long).

The result is like this

[image]

I've a [demo for Sierpinski triangles](https://github.com/spookiecookie/sierpinski), refer to comments in the code.

```
import java.util.List       ;
import java.util.LinkedList ;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D ;

/**
 * Generates Sierpinski triangle (▲).
 *    
 */
public class Sierpinski
{
    public int width ;
    public int height;
    /**
     * The smallest size of an area of the triangle.
     */
    public int limit ;

    /**
     * Lines of the triangle to be drawn.
     */
    public List<Line2D> lines = new LinkedList<>();

    public Sierpinski(int width, int height, int limit)
    {
        this.width  = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.limit  = limit;
    }

    /**
     * @return triangle area limit
     */
    public int getLimit()
    {
        return limit;
    }

    /**
     * @return width of the Sierpinski triangle
     */
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * @return height of the Sierpinski triangle
     */
    public int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * @return lines of the generated triangles
     */
    public List<Line2D> getLines()
    {
        return lines;
    }

    /**
     * @param p1 Starting point of the line.
     * @param p1 Ending   point of the line.
     */
    public void addLine(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)
    {
        getLines().add(
                new Line2D.Double(p1,p2));
    } 

    /**
     * @param top Top-most point of the triangle.
     * @param left Left-most point of the triangle.
     * @param right Right-most point of the triangle.
     *
     * @return area size of the triangle defined by supplied points.
     */
    public static double triangleArea(Point2D top, Point2D left, Point2D right)
    {
        return Math.abs(top.getX()*(right.getY()-left.getY()) + right.getX()*(left.getY() - top.getY()) + left.getX()*(top.getY()-right.getY())) / 2;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a Sierpinski triangle.
     * @see #generate(Point2D, Point2D)
     */
    public void generate()
    {
        generate(
                new Point2D.Double(getWidth() / 2, 0          ),
                new Point2D.Double(0             , getHeight() - 1 ),
                new Point2D.Double(getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1));
    }

    /**
     * Generates a Sierpinski triangle.
     */
    public void generate(Point2D top, Point2D left, Point2D right)
    {
        if (getLimit() < triangleArea(top,left,right)) 
        {
            Point2D leftMiddle   = 
                new Point2D.Double(
                        left.getX() + (top.getX()  - left.getX()) / 2,
                        top.getY()  + (left.getY() - top.getY())  / 2);
            Point2D rightMiddle  = 
                new Point2D.Double(
                        top.getX() + (right.getX() - top.getX()) / 2,
                        leftMiddle.getY());
            Point2D bottomMiddle =
                new Point2D.Double(
                        top.getX() ,
                        left.getY());

            generate(top        , leftMiddle  , rightMiddle );
            generate(leftMiddle , left        , bottomMiddle);
            generate(rightMiddle, bottomMiddle, right       );
        }
        else
        {
            addLine(top , right);
            addLine(top , left );
            addLine(left, right);
        }
    }
}
```